# Laravel 5.x override views for specific users

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade, templating

I am trying to override Views based on the logged in user `theme`. We have a `themes` table, each user has a FK to a `theme`.

My directory structure is as follows:

```
- resources
  - themes 
    - my_custom_theme
  - views
```

I've created a copy of `ViewServiceProvider` of my own and am extending the original one. This works fine, I am overriding `registerViewFinder()`, this also works fine. However at this stage of the app cycle, `auth()->user()` is not set so I cannot get their theme.

```
    /**
     * Register the view finder implementation.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function registerViewFinder()
    {
        $this->app->bind('view.finder', function ($app) {

            //dd($app['config']['view.paths']);

            //dd(auth()->user()->theme);

            return new FileViewFinder($app['files'], $app['config']['view.paths']);
        });
    }
```

I would like to generate a path based on the logged in users theme, so it can load from this directory instead. `resources/themes/my_custom_theme`.

**If I don't have access to the user here, what is the expected way to go about this?**

Many Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to achieve this by overriding the views using a Route Middleware. Anything before this had no access to `Auth::user()`.

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Illuminate\View\FileViewFinder;

class SwitchTheme
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @param  string|null  $guard
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, \Closure $next, $guard = null)
    {
        if (auth()->check()) {
            $paths = \Config::get('view.paths');
            $base = resource_path('themes');
            $theme = auth()->user()->theme;

            // add custom view path to the top of the path stack
            array_unshift($paths, "$base/$theme");

            // create a new instance of the Laravel FileViewFinder and set.
            $finder = new FileViewFinder(app()['files'], $paths);
            app()['view']->setFinder($finder);
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

I get the existing view paths array, and retrieve the users theme from the database. unshift the new path which in my case is the `resource_path/theme_name`.

I couldn't find a way to reset the paths, and using `$finder->addLocation` will put your theme path at the bottom of the stack so it won't override. In this case I needed to create a new instance of FileViewFinder giving it the new array of paths, and then overwrite the existing finder on `app()['view']`.

Nice and easy, just one middleware.

To load, just add `\App\Http\Middleware\SwitchTheme::class` to the `$middlewareGroups` array in `Kernel.php`